# Common Lisp Variable addFraction is unbound

Tags: variables, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, unbound

Why does it say that the variable `addFraction` is Unbound?

```
(defun addFraction (N1 D1 N2 D2)
  (format t "~d ~d"
          (+ (+ (lcm D1 D2) N1) (+ (lcm D1 D2) N2))
          (lcm D1 D2)))
```

When I ran the code it says this:

```
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10010B0523}>:
  The variable ADDFRACTION is unbound.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE   ] Retry using ADDFRACTION.
  1: [USE-VALUE  ] Use specified value.
  2: [STORE-VALUE] Set specified value and use it.
  3: [ABORT      ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV ADDFRACTION #<NULL-LEXENV>)
0]
```

Comment: I meant to write addFraction.. Edited it now

Comment: When I made the code, I copy pasted it in the sbcl command line, pressed enter, no errors were shown, when I called  `addFraction` then the error came up

Answer (score 1):

My Bad!

When I called the function I typed

`addFunction (1 2 1 4)`

Instead of

`(addFunction 1 2 1 4)`